# Accordion jQuery - Open one item at once and close others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a simple accordion, currently each item is opening, but I wanted to open one item at once and close others if opened

```js
$(".title").on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('title-mob-minus'); // This is for icon
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.link-list {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.title {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.link-list__items {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.link-list__items ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.link-list__items ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-list">
 <div class="title" role="heading">
  <a href="javascript:;">Accordion One</a>
 </div>
 <div class="link-list__items" style="display: none;">
  <ul role="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="link-list">
 <div class="title" role="heading">
  <a href="javascript:;">Accordion Two</a>
 </div>
 <div class="link-list__items" style="display: none;">
  <ul role="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract your toggle logic, then when clicking an accordion, close all the open ones, and then toggle the one clicked.

```js
function toggleTitles ($titles) {
  $titles.toggleClass('title-mob-minus'); // This is for icon
  $titles.next().slideToggle();
}

var $allTitles = $(".title").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // collapse all the other accordions that are open
  toggleTitles($allTitles.not(this).filter('.title-mob-minus'));
  // toggle this accordion
  toggleTitles($(this));
});
```

```css
.link-list {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.title {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.link-list__items {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.link-list__items ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.link-list__items ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-list">
  <div class="title" role="heading">
    <a href="javascript:;">Accordion One</a>
  </div>
  <div class="link-list__items" style="display: none;">
    <ul role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="link-list">
  <div class="title" role="heading">
    <a href="javascript:;">Accordion Two</a>
  </div>
  <div class="link-list__items" style="display: none;">
    <ul role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, its perfectly as per my requirement and even the toggle class for icon is working fine. thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$(this).next().slideToggle();
```

to

```
$(".link-list__items").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
$(this).next().slideToggle();
```

```js
$(".title").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('title-mob-minus'); // This is for icon
  $(".link-list__items").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();  
  return false;
});
```

```css
.link-list {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.title {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.link-list__items {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.link-list__items ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.link-list__items ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-list">
 <div class="title" role="heading">
  <a href="javascript:;">Accordion One</a>
 </div>
 <div class="link-list__items" style="display: none;">
  <ul role="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="link-list">
 <div class="title" role="heading">
  <a href="javascript:;">Accordion Two</a>
 </div>
 <div class="link-list__items" style="display: none;">
  <ul role="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP should also remove title-mob-minus from the titles

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".title").on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('title-mob-minus'); // This is for icon
  //hide all list-items
  $(".link-list__items").hide();
  //show sibling list items
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.link-list {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.title {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.link-list__items {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.link-list__items ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.link-list__items ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-list">
 <div class="title" role="heading">
  <a href="javascript:;">Accordion One</a>
 </div>
 <div class="link-list__items" style="display: none;">
  <ul role="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="link-list">
 <div class="title" role="heading">
  <a href="javascript:;">Accordion Two</a>
 </div>
 <div class="link-list__items" style="display: none;">
  <ul role="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Accordion Inner Item</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```